# Adding grid lines to a ggplot with a background image

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridlines, ggpubr

I have my made a plot using ggplot2 and use a graphic as a background. Now I want to add grids to make it more clear and I've got stuck. My ggplot2 function:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(df), aes(x = Year, y = Number)) +
  background_image(jpg) +
  geom_line(color = "black", size = 2) +
  labs(title = "Title", y = "Name1", x = "Name2")
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: I've tried theme and grids function but I couldn't see any gridlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example from `ggpubr::background_image` this can be achieved by setting `panel.background = element_blank()` and `panel.ontop = TRUE`. Try this:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

img.file <- system.file(file.path("images", "background-image.png"),
                        package = "ggpubr")
img <- png::readPNG(img.file)

# Plot with background image
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length))+
  background_image(img)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Species), color = "white")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.ontop = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**EDIT:** An alterantive approach would be to draw the grid lines manually using `geom_vline` and `geom_hline`:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

img.file <- system.file(file.path("images", "background-image.png"),
                        package = "ggpubr")
img <- png::readPNG(img.file)

# Plot with background image
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length))+
  background_image(img) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Species), color = "white") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(5, 6, 7, 8), color = "white") +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Species), color = "white")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank You very much it works perfectly. Is there any option to get this geom_boxplot on top of everything? Now its "behind" the grid lines and it isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi @Aleksandra. I just made an edit. An alterantive approach to achieve what you want is to draw the grid lines manually using `geom_vline` and `geom_hline`. This way the boxplot will be plotted on top of the grid-lines.